# Blackberry 10 contact pic to byte array

Tags: c++, qt, contacts, blackberry-10

I am working on migration application. I have to transfer blackberry 10 contacts to android.

I am getting problem in transferring contact pic. I am getting the uri of the pic, create file and try to read the bytes.

```
ContactPhoto contactPhoto = contact.primaryPhoto();
QString photo = contactPhoto.originalPhoto();
//photo = file:///accounts/1000/pimdata/_startup_data/contacts/2/img-tnqpx0.jpg
if (!photo.isEmpty()){
    QFile file(photo);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
       qDebug() <<"file.readAll() IF" <<file.readAll() <<endl;
    }else{
       qDebug() <<"file.readAll() ELSE" <<endl;
    }
    vcardString += "PHOTO;JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:" + (file.readAll() + "\n");
}
```

But else part of the below snip of code is executing

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    qDebug() <<"file.readAll() IF" <<file.readAll() <<endl;
}else{
    qDebug() <<"file.readAll() ELSE" <<endl;
}
```

How I read bytes from below uri

> file:///accounts/1000/pimdata/_startup_data/contacts/2/img-tnqpx0.jpg

Comment: I just checked with my app FileSystem and I'm able to read every pictures that are in "/accounts/1000/pimdata/_startup_data/contacts/" subfolders. I haven't looked at the code yet as I'm away from home but it's probably close to what you are using, can you try with and without "file://" to see if it makes a difference. I'll look at my code later and will post if I spot something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, removing `file://` from the url works.

Here's the code I used to test :

```
    bb::pim::contacts::ContactPhoto contactPhoto = contact.primaryPhoto();
    QString photo = contactPhoto.originalPhoto();
    if (!photo.isEmpty()){
        QFile file(photo.remove("file://"));
        if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
           qDebug() <<"file.readAll() IF" <<file.readAll() <<endl;
        }else{
           qDebug() <<"file.readAll() ELSE" <<endl;
        }
    }
```

Please note that you need to leave one `/` in front of the url, so your picture url shared in OP would look like :

```
/accounts/1000/pimdata/_startup_data/contacts/2/img-tnqpx0.jpg
```

Also, if your goal is to create a VCard vcf file, you don't need to manually create the VCard file content, don't even need to read the bytes of the photo file, the `contactToVCard` function will do that for you.

```
QByteArray vcard = contactService.contactToVCard(contact.id(), bb::pim::contacts::VCardPhotoEncoding::BASE64, -1);
qDebug() << "vcard:" << vcard;
```

Comment: Thanks @Roger Leblanc, I was preparing vCard manually you told me about API that is awesome. With this API I am get rid of it with all this manual preparation.